# Wifi connection not working with Intel NUC + Wireless AC 7620

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, intel-nuc

I am posting here with the hope to get help to solve the problems I have with my wifi connection on my Intel NUC with the Wireless AC 7620 on Ubuntu 15.04.

I have copied below the output of the Wireless Info Script, but before some short  history and description about the problems I have.

I built my NUC about a year ago and installed Ubuntu 14.04 straight after for a media center use. Everything was working perfect, with fast and stable wifi connection. When Ubuntu 14.10 was released, I didn't upgrade (I wanted to stay on a LTS version) but kept doing the regular updates.

Then one day to another (somewhere around October / November 2014 I would say), everything went wrong: connection to the wifi was lost on a regular basis, sometimes every few minutes, transfer rate was dropping so low it would take several minutes to display the Google homepage, the connection would get lost and never come back.

I went through several forums/websites/wikis and tried many things. What got the best results I think was to disable the power management with iwconfig. Disabling/renabling the wifi and/or network was working also sometimes. Upgrading to newer Ubuntu version was sometimes improving the situation, sometimes not.

Today, I went back home and wanted to use my NUC again and the situation is worse as ever. Here are the symptoms :

- The NUC quickly connects to my wifi network at startup.
- The signal strength is good, to about 75 % I would say.
- The connection is stable.
- It is impossible to get to any website. If I try to reach the Google homepage for example, the Firefox wheel will turn for ever but nothing shows up.
- Trying to update with apt-get update does trigger some data transfer, but at a very low transfer rate (I cancelled it after five minutes and it wasn't finished).

My router/internet access is a Freebox v5, but I think the problem really comes from the NUC/Ubuntu, as I am also running a Windows 7 desktop and a Debian Jessie nettop on wifi and none of them have these problems.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Any additional command line or test, let me know and I will do it ASAP !

Note: I removed all wifi networks that weren't mine from iwlist scan to stay below the 30000 characters limit.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 Jul 2015 21:14 CEST +0200

Booted last: 22 Jul 2015 20:53 CEST +0200

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 16 17:15:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V [8086:1559] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2054]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4170]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c71f Logitech, Inc. diNovo Mini Wireless Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c71e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0b07 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0d7d:1900 Phison Electronics Corp. USB Thumb Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                278528  0 
mac80211              724992  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               196608  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              540672  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_soc_rt5640         94208  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          196608  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.51  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2210 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1637945 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:258557 (258.5 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"TXNPK188"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=180 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:199   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       720     1  0 20:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 7260 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.19.0-22-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               25.17.12.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     TXNPK188
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       55085fca-cbd0-4126-bdda-1d6e4f39c6bd
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     180 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   55085fca-cbd0-4126-bdda-1d6e4f39c6bd | TXNPK188
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.0.51/24, gw = 192.168.0.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             212.27.40.241
IP4.DNS[2]:                             212.27.40.240
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64, gw = ::

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection I218-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3.2-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.6-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off

SSID             BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY     ACTIVE  * 
FreeWifi_secure  <MAC 'FreeWifi_secure' [AC9]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 802.1X  no        
--               <MAC '--' [AN2]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2         no        
FreeWifi_secure  <MAC 'FreeWifi_secure' [AC7]>  Infra  8     2447 MHz  54 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X  no        
FreeWifi         <MAC 'FreeWifi' [AC8]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  --           no        
FreeWifi         <MAC 'FreeWifi' [AN5]>  Infra  8     2447 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  --           no        
TXNPK188         <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  71      ▂▄▆_  WPA1         yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TXNPK188]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TXNPK188 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TXNPK188 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=manual
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Paris (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      5   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]>
                    Channel:13
                    Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)
                    Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TXNPK188"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000001ced635cc
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     84DEF0B250352D8D14C9DD1
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C7:D4:40:34:4C:0B:3A:C2:A3:CE:C2:AE:B9:72:2E:CF:6C:AE:73:91
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-22-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     88CC41451370601B0D885E4
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C7:D4:40:34:4C:0B:3A:C2:A3:CE:C2:AE:B9:72:2E:CF:6C:AE:73:91
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     97E94F4448EBBA00BC45455
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C7:D4:40:34:4C:0B:3A:C2:A3:CE:C2:AE:B9:72:2E:CF:6C:AE:73:91
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-22-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     E61EB836E1B33C2A2918485
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C7:D4:40:34:4C:0B:3A:C2:A3:CE:C2:AE:B9:72:2E:CF:6C:AE:73:91
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x1559 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b1 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.464732] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    3.518660] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.460499] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[    7.916726] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]>
[    7.920483] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[    7.922310] wlan0: authenticated
[    7.928438] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[    7.942641] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[    7.943963] wlan0: associated
[  359.516348] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  359.531246] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  367.152590] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[  370.627806] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]>
[  370.631010] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  370.632766] wlan0: authenticated
[  370.633913] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  370.644779] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  370.655915] wlan0: associated
[  495.292650] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  504.186814] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[  507.569951] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]>
[  507.573064] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  507.575888] wlan0: authenticated
[  507.576642] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  507.585643] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'TXNPK188' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  507.586893] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a NUC as well and found that several minor quirks were fixed when I updated the BIOS to the latest. I urge you to do the same.

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is *not* set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then, set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland.

Reboot the NUC and let us know if stability is improved.

Answer (score 1):

Hi again and thanks for the feedback,

So here is what I did:

- BIOS update: done with the release of June 12th 2015. The version previously installed was about one year old.
- Router settings: I had selected WPA (TKIP+AES) because it is stated in my router interface that this is the prefered mode (does not say why though). My other choices are: WEP (but I would disregard this due to low security), WPA (TKIP) or WPA (AES/CCMP). Do you recommend one in particular ?
- Router channel was changed from 13 to 6.
- Exclusive use of N mode of the router: the option does not exist one way or another in the interface. However I am quite sure that the router is not in N only mode because my nettop only support B and G and still is capable of connecting to the wifi.
- Router reboot done.
- The output of iw reg get was indeed 00.
- REGDOMAIN has been changed from 00 to FR.
- The output of iw reg get is now FR.
- NUC reboot done.

I made of few tests yesterday and the wifi response is clearly better. I was able to update through apt-get with a download speed within 500 to 700 ko/s (which is OK I think). Internet browsing was very fast. Today is maybe slightly slower, but hard to tell.

It looks like the issue is solved, but unfortunately, I have been used to these temporary improvements in the past. Let's consider this closed for now and I will post back if the problems show up after a few weeks/reboots/updates.

Thanks again !

Comment: I recommend WPA(AES/CCMP). I don't think anything here is temporary. Once set and working, you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

i also had this issue with intel nuc skull. driver and bios update didn't help.
but switching the channel in my router from "auto" to channel "1" did the job.