# Wifi ridiculously slow on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and a Frontier MI424WR Router

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, internet, atheros

My Acer Aspire E5 575G has a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377. I have tried reinstalling my kernel, I have reinstalled drivers(ath10k), installing backport, have turned off powersaving, have installed wicd, etc...
only thing that has slightly helped is disabling WMM in the router settings. My kernel version is 4.10.0-42-generic.
Typical speeds right next to the router are 15 mbps up and down. I have a 50/50 plan. 50+ mbps is my ethernet speed. when bluetooth is on, my mbps is half of the current slow wifi. 
Here are some of the commands y'all often ask for:

```
  tcr-g@TCR:~/backports-20151120$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 3c:a0:67:b7:f9:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:b4000000-b41fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: enp4s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: a8:1e:84:8c:f3:95
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4204000-b4204fff memory:b4200000-b4203fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

tcr-g@TCR:~/backports-20151120$ dmesg | grep ath
[    2.605692] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.753058] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.753072] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.756304] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[    3.756307] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.756709] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[    3.826673] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[    5.624886] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    5.631635] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    5.631636] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    5.631637] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    5.631638] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    5.635286] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.219280] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   17.699227] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   17.699229] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   17.706891] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[   17.706892] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   17.706892] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   17.706893] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[   17.706893] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[   17.706894] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[   17.706894] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
[21149.836191] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to install key for vdev 0 peer 00:7f:28:79:03:4e: -110
[21176.174975] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[21176.174976] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[21176.187707] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[21176.187708] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[21176.187709] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[21176.187710] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[21176.187711] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[21176.187711] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[21176.187712] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
[22095.165638] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.267894] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.370380] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.472716] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.575322] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.677724] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.780064] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.882586] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22095.984765] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22096.087341] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[22106.315653] ath10k_warn: 10 callbacks suppressed
[22106.315691] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[24125.507965] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[25301.490471] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[25964.493815] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[28246.217197] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[28573.272844] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[28575.380226] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[28887.948033] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[30208.862759]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x193/0x290
[30208.862822]  path_openat+0x2ac/0x1430
[30208.862883]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad
[30564.955587] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[30565.470017] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[30899.273952] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[30899.274179] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[30903.578321] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[31557.410765] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[34913.254867] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[34913.254871] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[34913.270099] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[34913.270100] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[34913.270101] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[34913.270102] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[34913.270103] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[34913.270103] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[34913.270105] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
[35173.320845] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[35173.320849] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[35173.336678] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[35173.336678] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[35173.336679] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[35173.336680] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[35173.336681] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[35173.336682] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[35173.336683] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
[39817.251694] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to install key for vdev 0 peer 00:7f:28:79:03:4e: -110
[39817.375135] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[39817.375138] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[39817.384885] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[39817.384886] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[39817.384887] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[39817.384888] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[39817.384889] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[39817.384890] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[39817.384891] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
tcr-g@TCR:~/backports-20151120$ sudo iw reg get
[sudo] password for tcr-g: 
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 17), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
tcr-g@TCR:~/backports-20151120$ 
tcr-g@TCR:~/backports-20151120$ modinfo ath10k_pci; dkms status
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     55269025DC0881FB8B580CD
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000050sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000042sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000046sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000056sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000040sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000041sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath10k_core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.90, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.90, 4.10.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.90, 4.4.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
tcr-g@TCR:~/backports-20151120$ sudo iwlist scan
[sudo] password for tcr-g: 
vmnet1    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0f1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

vmnet8    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"delbhome"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000001bdbf8475
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000864656C62686F6D65
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030108
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C131B0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1608001B00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1B
tcr-g@TCR:~$ tracepath mtu
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home                        1.350ms 
 1:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home                        1.247ms 
 2:  47.187.192.1                                         10.938ms 
 3:  172.102.52.82                                        16.723ms 
 4:  ae7---0.scr01.dlls.tx.frontiernet.net                14.487ms 
 5:  ae1---0.cbr01.dlls.tx.frontiernet.net                12.700ms 
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  10ge3-15.core1.dal1.he.net                           24.767ms 
 9:  100ge4-2.core1.phx2.he.net                           49.334ms asymm 11 
10:  100ge11-2.core1.lax2.he.net                          64.731ms 
11:  xerocole-inc.gigabitethernet2-9.core1.lax2.he.net    40.325ms 
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500 
tcr-g@TCR:~$
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried all the steps here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/651462/wifi-connection-not-working-with-intel-nuc-wireless-ac-7620/651474#651474

Comment: Yes. I have done all of those

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `sudo iwlist scan` Please omit any access points aside from your own and obscure any MAC addresses.

Comment: I added iwlist scan

Comment: Have you done some tests to rule out your router? Not saying that you haven't, but are you getting faster speeds with a different device/OS?

Comment: My Older Dell laptop with an intel centrino , and is on Ubuntu 17.10 receives the same problem as my new PC. My phone, a samsung s7, recieves 50 mbps.

Comment: It appears, from your scan, that the router is still set to WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and also probably auto channel selection. Please retrace the steps I suggested and reboot the router after making all the changes.

Comment: I have tried setting my router to specific channels (3,8,11,6) to no avail, the router is on WPA2 with a preshared ASCII key

Comment: What is the value of your `MTU`? `ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep MTU`. Install and run the `tracepath` pkg/utility to see optimum `MTU`.

Comment: tcr-g@TCR:~$ ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep MTU
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

Comment: Your `MTU` is too big for Wi-Fi, causing packet splitting, twice as many packets, and appearant slowth. Install and run `tracepath` to find the good `MTU`.

Answer (score -1):

Decrease the MTU value. With MTU 1500 Wifi lags a lot.

```
wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a8:6b:ad:0d:b7:bf  
          inet addr:192.168.*.*  Bcast:192.168.*.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:300  Metric:1
          RX packets:138453 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61733823 (61.7 MB)  TX bytes:9958448 (9.9 MB)
```

Comment: That change reduced my speed. With MTU 1500=13.8Mbps, and with MTU 300=8.6Mbps. I have a QCA9377 in a Lenovo Ideapad 330S running Ubuntu 18.04